# Portable JDK for Minecraft modding

Tags: java, portability, minecraft

this is probably going to spark a lot of 'Duplicate of ...' but I really need to know if this is do-able.

I'm currently attempting to make mods for Minecraft with the Minecraft Coders Pack and Eclipse Java EE.

I am not an admin on my machine so I can't get JDK which MCP needs.

All I need basically is the files from JDK, I'm not having problems with setting JAVA_HOME and PATH as I can set those dirs manually in the de-compiler.

I need JDK 6

Comment: staticchaos.freeoda.com/java/ <-- I think I need something like this but only version 6

Comment: So just install JDK on a different PC and copy the installation folder to the other workstation.

Comment: THAT ^ is a great idea, ill give it a try

Answer (score 0):

I have done this myself because I was in the same position. I tried copying the JDK as well, but that didn't work, could be a mistake on my part.

I am using OpneJDK now, and that works perfectly with intelij-idea, I'm sure it works with Eclipse as well.

http://openjdk.java.net/